# VS 2017 - Team Explorer Commit - Shortcut

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, team-explorer

What is the fastest way to commit into git from VisualStudio with and/or without TeamExplorer setup.

Currently I have to:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
2. <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Switch to changes
4. <kbd>Tab</kbd>,<kbd>Tab</kbd>
5. *Write a commit message*
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *(custom shortcut for Team.Git.CommitAndSync)*

Comment: Hmm probably `git commit -a -m "message"<enter>` from the package management console... prepend `git add *` to stage everything before committing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. The default key binding to go straight to the Git Changes page in Team Explorer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>,<kbd>G</kbd>.  The command is `Team.Git.GoToGitChanges` if you'd like to bind it to a different key.
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to reach the commit message textbox.
3. Write your commit message.
4. Usually followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to trigger the Commit button, but a custom key binding for the Commit and Sync command is needed in your scenario.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, managed to get it to work with setting Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+Q to `(Global) Git.GoToGitChanges` and `Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+Q` to `(Team Explorer) Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+Q. As long as I don't `CommitAndSync` Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+Q goes to commit message textbox straight away, letting me type in the commit, then hit Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+Q again